# how to add fallback to subroutines that are not available in some module versions?

Tags: perl

I am working in a code that targets perl 5.12.2

I need to decode a base64 string, however it uses the schema for "URL applications", and in modern perl versions I can just use `MIME::Base64::decode_base64url` however this function is not available in older versions of perl.

It is an easy function and I can write 5 lines of code that substitute it, but I'd like to use decode_base64url if available.

I know I can do `MIME::Base64->can("decode_base64url")`, my question is about the approach. I can do something like this:

```perl
sub _decode_base64url {
    my $s = shift;
    
    state $decode_base64url = MIME::Base64->can("decode_base64url");
    
    return $decode_base64url->($s) if $decode_base64url;

    # fallback
    $s =~ tr[-_][+/];
    $s .= '=' while length($s) % 4;
    return decode_base64($s);
}
```

however, thinking in a more generic solution, what is the pattern to add functions in this case (like a polyfill in javascript) ?

Perhaps I should create a secondary package that defines a decode_base64url as fallback and decide to use one or another based on use .. if ?

Comment: I do not have Perl 5.12.2 around, but the current MIME::Base64 (3.16) tests cleanly on Perl 5.12.5. I would make this an answer, but it does not address your larger question.

Comment: I am working on a very large codebase and people are a little bit afraid of break things, also the cost of retest everything is high. However this is my initial target, it should work on newer versions of Perl. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just rearrange your code a bit:

```
sub _decode_base64url {
    my $s = shift;

    state $decode_base64url = MIME::Base64->can("decode_base64url") || sub {
        my $s = shift;
        $s =~ tr[-_][+/];
        $s .= '=' while length($s) % 4;
        return decode_base64($s);
    };
    
    return $decode_base64url->($s);
}
```

The key to the above is that if the named subroutine actually exists, the `->can()` method returns a reference to it. If not, the right-hand side of the Boolean or (`||`) gets executed, and evaluates to a reference to the anonymous sub.

**Note** that the above is cold code. That is, if I put it in *fubar.PL* and do

```
 perl -MMIME::Base64 fubar.PL
```

it exits without error, but of course your subroutine has not actually been called.